# How to map uint in NHibernate with SQL Server 2005

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, nhibernate, orm, uint32

I have a property of type uint on my entity. Something like:

```
public class Enity
{
   public uint Count {get;set;}
}
```

When I try to persist that into the SQL Server 2005 database, I get an exception

> Dialect does not support DbType.UInt32

What would be the easiest way to workaround this. I could for example store it as long in the DB.
I only don't know how to tell that to NHibernate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest, *most official* solution would probably be to write a user type.

Take an example, like [this one](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rhouston/archive/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype.aspx) and adapt it. If you have many `uint`'s, it is worth to have a user type.

```
<property name="Prop" type="UIntUserType"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ultimately ended up doing. Thanks for help guys, all of you.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried this so not sure if this will work for you but you could try creating your own Dialect and registering that in the web.config/app.config

Dialect class:

```
public class MyDialect:MsSql2005Dialect
{
    public MyDialect()
    {            
        RegisterColumnType(System.Data.DbType.UInt32, "bigint");            
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
configuration>
 <configSections>
  <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
 </configSections>

                <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
   <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider, NHibernate</property>
   <property name="connection.connection_string">
    Server=127.0.0.1; Initial Catalog=thedatabase; Integrated Security=SSPI
   </property>
   <property name="dialect">MyDialect</property>
   <property name="current_session_context_class">managed_web</property>
  </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
    <!-- other app specific config follows -->

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<property name="Prop" type="long"/>
```

Comment: Then may be you should describe the problem a little better

Comment: This *did* work for me... with type="long" SchemaExport exports the field as BIGINT

Comment: what version of NHibernate do you use?

Comment: NH 2.0.1GA... are you getting the same exception after defining type="long"?

Comment: just tested this, seems to work... http://code.google.com/p/mausch/source/browse/trunk/NHibernateDirtyTest/NHibernateDirtyTest/SessionDirtyTests.cs?spec=svn161&r=161

Comment: It does work for save, but throws a cast exception during retrieve, due to quirky bahavior of CLR and what I'd call a bug in NH. It tries to unbox object holding long into an uint, which throws InvalidCastException, because CLR does not perform numeric conversions during unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add another private "mirror"-property.

```
public class Enity
{
   public uint Count {get;set;}

   private long CountAsLong 
   { 
     get { return Convert.ToInt64(Count); } 
     set { Count = Convert.ToUInt(value); }
   }
}

<property name="CountAsLong" type="long"/>
```

Of course you should do this **only** if it could not be solved by the mapping.