# Support for UINt32 in NHibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I am trying to support UInt32 in my application.By looking example given at this location,i wrote my code.
  [NHibernate - How to store UInt32 in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309072/nhibernate-how-to-store-uint32-in-database). In my hbm file i defined property tag:

```
           <property name="Uint16Var" column="Uint16Var" 
           type="datatypeSupported.UInt32Type,  datatypeSupported"  />
```

and i also defined a UInt32Type  class like this:

```
     using System;
     using NHibernate;
     using NHibernate.SqlTypes;
     using NHibernate.UserTypes;

    namespace datatypeSupported
    {
     public class UInt32Type : IUserType
    {

    public object NullSafeGet(System.Data.IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        int? i = (int?)NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);
        return (UInt32?)i;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(System.Data.IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        UInt32? u = (UInt32?)value;
        int? i = (Int32?)u;
        NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeSet(cmd, i, index);  
    }

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(Nullable<UInt32>);
        }
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new SqlType[] { SqlTypeFactory.Int32 };
        }
    } public object Assemble(object cached, object owner) 
    { 
        return cached; 
    } 

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    { 
        return value;
    } 

    public object Disassemble(object value) 
    {
        return value; 
    } 

    public int GetHashCode(object x) 
    { 
        return x.GetHashCode(); 
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    } 

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner) 
    { 
        return original; 
    } 

    public new bool Equals(object x, object y) 
    { 
        return x != null && x.Equals(y);
    }
}
```

}

but still when i try to save my entity, it gives a error "Dialect does not support DbType.UInt32".What type of changes i required to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Write a custom dialect that adds support to `UInt32` type. Depending on the database you are using, inherit from one of the known dialects. I.e., for SQL Server, you could have something like this:

```
public class CustomMsSqlDialect : MsSql2008Dialect
{
    protected override void RegisterNumericTypeMappings()
    {
        base.RegisterNumericTypeMappings();
        RegisterColumnType(DbType.UInt32, "INT");
    }
}
```

To register the dialect with FluentNHibernate:

```
Fluently.Configure().Database(
    MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.Dialect<CustomMsSqlDialect>()...)
```

And with XML:

```
<property name="dialect">CustomMsSqlDialect, AssemblyName</property>
```

Comment: Thanks sir.I want to implement in ms Sql server 2008, but i am not able to find any suitable or similar method like RegisterNumericTypeMappings() in msSql2008 dialect to override. Can u please help me with SqlServer2008 dialect.

Comment: Actually, it's in `MsSql2000Dialect` class, that `MsSql2008Dialect` class inherits from: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/MsSql2000Dialect.cs You should be able to override, I just checked with latest NHibernate version.

Comment: @ Miroslav Popovic: still i am getting the same error.I can't find any method.I am using hibernate (Version: 3.2.0.4000).

Comment: @rajeshKumar Make sure you are inheriting from the right class (`MsSql2008Dialect`) and that your method is named correctly (`RegisterNumericTypeMappings`). Just checked the older NHibernate version source - 2.1, and it looks the same there.

Comment: @ Miroslav Popovic: Sry sir...But i just copied paste your code..as given above..But still i am getting the same error-"no suitable method found to override".I checked all interface definition but still i am not able to find that method.In Dialect interface i can find this method - protected internal void RegisterHibernateType(DbType code, string name),but not RegisterNumericTypeMappings(). Please help me.

Comment: @rajeshKumar Are you sure you are inheriting from `MsSql2008Dialect` class? You can also use `RegisterColumnType` in your CustomSqlDialect constructor instead of overriding. See KaraT's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/891481/119230